# Finding Equivalence Classes for Infinite Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be the relation on the set of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ defined as follows: for all $q, r \in  \Bbb Q$, $qRr$ iff $q − r \in \Bbb Z$.

Then $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb Q$.

What is the equivalence class of 3?

Comment: What do you know about this question? What you have tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well I found it is an equivalence relation. But I'm not sure how to find the equivalence class of 3 or what that even means.

Comment: Suppose $q \sim 3$. Then $q-3 \in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $q = 3+z$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, so what is true of $q$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of equivalence classes?

Comment: @AWertheim that makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Comment: @shamu11: glad I could help! :)

Comment: Just a quick question, what does the ∼ represent in this?

Comment: I've used $\sim$ to represent "$q$ is equivalent to $3$ under the relation $R$".